# Love letter: If you discard a constable and lose, do you get an affection token?

Tags: love-letter, love-letter-premium

In the rules, if you are eliminated with the constable in your discard pile, you gain an affection token.

If I discard the constable, and then lose on points at the end of the round, have I been eliminated and thus get an affection token? Or did I just lose, and not get an affection token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You must be eliminated before the end of the round.**

Text from Constable:

> If this card is in your discard pile when you are *knocked out of the round*, gain an Affection Token.

(Emphasis mine)

In the rulebook for the original Love Letter, the phrase "knocked out of the round" is used several times, and in each case it is only referring to being eliminated while the round is still going. Example:

> If you discard the Princess—no
>   matter how or why—she has tossed 
>   16
>   your letter into the fire. You are
>   *knocked out of the round*.

(Emphasis mine)

Under the rules for "End of a round", no mention is made of being knocked out:

> The player with the
>   highest ranked person wins the
>   round.

So being "knocked out of a round" is something that specifically happens from the effects of a card that was discarded.

Comment: OK - so for clarification, you can

1. Win a round by being the survivor with the highest points
2. Lose the round by surviving but not having the highest points
3. Get knocked out of the round by some action, like discarding the princess or being attacked by a guard

Only in the 3rd case do you get an affection token by using the constable, so try hard to get knocked out once you've discarded him!

Comment: Yes, that's correct.